# Recommendation of protocol for IoT with Android?

Tags: android, http, ibm-cloud, mqtt

---

I'm developing a basic IoT configuration and I'm stuck with the decision of the protocol for the Android App communication.

The system goes like this:

```
Atmega328 <-Serial-> ESP8266 <-MQTT-> IBM Bluemix <-??-> AndroidApp
```

In IBM Bluemix I have a Cloud Foundry App coded in Node-Red, this connects to a IoT Watson platform which controls the MQTT communication with the ESP8266.

Now, I was thinking on doing http communication inside Android, but I couldn't find a way to do it from the Bluemix side. So I'm thinking of doing MQTT instead.

**Is this a good choice?**

**Do you have any other suggestion?**

**From the Android side, I want to be able to receive notifications as well, is this possible with MQTT?**

Thanks in advance, any guidance on this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please read the Stack Overflow help on what type of questions to avoid asking. Asking questions about what is "best" and asking for suggestions end up with opinion based answers which are off topic

Comment: Also do not cross post the same question to multiple Stack Exchange sites https://android.stackexchange.com/q/191728/16243

Comment: Removed the "best" word from the title of the question. Nonetheless, after reading the Stack Overflow help, I still think it's a valid question.

Comment: Recommendations are also off topic

Comment: I don't know what word do you want me to use. But I think the question is valid. I have a specific problem with 2 possible solutions and I'm asking for other possible solutions.